# Как сделать зажатую кнопку в python

Tags: python, button

Нужно сделать что бы python зажал кнопку "W" на 2 секунды. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

`pip3 install pyautogui`

[with pyautogui:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682388/pyautogui-press-key-for-x-seconds:)

```
def hold_W (hold_time):
    import time, pyautogui
    start = time.time()
    while time.time() - start < hold_time:
        pyautogui.press('w')
```